# Isomorphism between Rings $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{u}{v}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{v}]$, u,v relatively prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, prime-numbers, ideals, factoring

Let $u$ and $v$ be relatively prime integers, and let $R'$ be the ring obtained from $\mathbb{Z}$ by adjoining an element $\alpha$ with the relation $v\alpha=u$. Prove that $R'$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{u}{v}]$ and also to $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{v}]$.

This is from Artin's chapter on Factoring.

**Edit:** My professor changed the problem slightly to assume that $R'=\mathbb{Z}[\frac{u}{v}]$, so that we only need to show that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{v}]$. Supposed to make the problem more do-able, but still seems daunting...

So I know by definition that
$$\mathbb{Z}[\frac{u}{v}]=\{a_0+a_1(\frac{u}{v})+a_2(\frac{u}{v})^2+\cdots+a_n(\frac{u}{v})^n|a_i\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$

So since $u,v$ are relatively prime, I know there exist integers $r,s$ so that $ur+vs=1$ (not sure if this is helpful information). I also know then that $\frac{u}{v}\notin\mathbb{Z}$ so we must have $\frac{u}{v}\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Also, if you consider a mapping $\phi:\mathbb{Z}[x]\to\mathbb{Z}[\frac{u}{v}]$ which sends $x\to\frac{u}{v}$ note that $vx-u\in ker(\phi)$. Somehow I am supposed to deduce that $R'=\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(vx-u)}$ (why?). Not sure what to do with this information.

She also said to look at
$$\frac{1}{p}=a_0+a_1(\frac{u}{v})+a_2(\frac{u}{v})^2+\cdots+a_n(\frac{u}{v})^n$$
(Why do we set this equal to $\frac{1}{p}$?)
And see that
$$\frac{v^n}{p}=a_0v^n+a_1uv^{n-1}+a_2u^2v^{n-2}+\cdots+a_nu^n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
is true if $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{u}{v}]$ is a field, but it isn't (why?) but supposedly it is an integral domain...

If you can, I would really appreciate it if you could clarify any of my above questions. And I'm not seeing how this is getting me closer to showing there is an isomorphism from $R'\to\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{v}]$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only are $\Bbb Z[\frac{u}{v}]$ and $\Bbb Z[\frac{1}{v}]$ isomorphic, they are *equal* subrings of $\Bbb Q$ (a stronger condition).

If $\alpha,\beta$ are elements of some common ring extension of $R$ then $\,R[\alpha]\subseteq R[\beta]~\Leftrightarrow~\alpha\in R[\beta]$.

Consider $\frac{u}{v},\frac{1}{v}\in\Bbb Q$ where $R=\Bbb Z$: $\phantom{}$ as $\frac{u}{v}\in\Bbb Z[\frac{1}{v}]$ is obvious, you must show $\frac{\color{Blue}{1}}{v}\in\Bbb Z[\frac{\color{Green}{u}}{v}]$.

We want to write $\color{Blue}1$ in terms of $\color{Green}{u}$ (mod $v$). Bezout says $\frac{1}{v}=\frac{mu+nv}{v}=m\frac{u}{v}+n$ for some $m,n$.

Comment: Thank you Sea Turtles! It was still a fun challenge to prove the lemma that if $\alpha\in R[\beta]$ then $R[\alpha]\subseteq R[\beta]$ and then proving subset in both directions (by proving an element of one can be written in the form of the other) to show ring equality... This was extremely helpful direction and your guidance was very much appreciated for my understanding, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ By Bezout, $(u,v) = 1\,\Rightarrow\, mu+nv = 1\,\Rightarrow\, m\, \dfrac{u}v + n = \dfrac{1}v,\,$ for some $\,m,n\in \Bbb Z$